# As Buddhists, what do you make out of the tragedy of Tibet?

Tags: history, tibetan-buddhism, tibetan

I finished watching two movies on the life of H.H the Dalai Lama ([Kundun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFm8oP9c9Hs) and [Seven years in Tibet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSyr_vJ5t3k&t=18s)) which also highlight the tragedy of Tibet. Historically Tibet can be said as the only country which has dedicated itself to the attainment of Nibbana (take this with a pinch of salt). A huge amount of cultural heritage and Buddhist documents must have been lost during the cultural revolution.

So what do you make out of the tragedy of Tibet?

Do we learn any lessons about Karma?

Do you think that for protection of Dhamma Tibet should have indulged in dealing with arms?

If you are a Vajrayana, do you care for Liberation of Tibet?

***P.S: Not being judgemental towards the Chinese.***

Comment: Should we close this as 100% opinion-based?

Comment: Yes, it is kind of, but can it not be given the leverage of being a question of, 'doing a meaningful contribution towards the bigger understanding of Buddhist life'.

Comment: Actually you know, I can seperate those questions and make it appear like they will have objective answers. But in current form it make better sense, so I would suggest to not close it. But if that might affect the BU.stack its your call.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov I think it's a polling question again, i.e. it's asking about/for the opinion of every user on a (random) topic. Just because it's asked here doesn't automatically make it a question about Buddhism. And even just because it's asked about a Buddhist country doesn't make it a question about Buddhism or about Buddhist culture. It's nearly on-topic but it should concentrate more on being a specific question. Also asking "lessons learned about kamma" is more or less a duplicate of the earlier question about kamma and Jews in the Holocaust isn't it: so maybe not that question again.

Comment: We've had questions about arms before, so I don't know what good asking about arms in Tibet might be. And asking "do you care?" is IMO a weak (open-ended) question, like "I can't think of a good question to ask, but say whatever you think is important about it." Maybe it would be better for a discussion site (elsewhere) than for Q+A (here). Anyway I closed another topic recently for being a polling question, I think I should do the same for this one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [polling question](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254). You could also use [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism) for this topic if you want to.

Comment: @ChrisW I do get your point, and not arguing to re-open it, but you know what, sometimes when the context changes, the way we look at our understanding of something also changes. For an e.g. when the gravity is pondered for heavenly objects we use space-time curve to solve the equations rather than Newton's laws. As with the changing context, we need better understanding. I know the Karma deal, but with Tibet, it was something to be rethought as it let me wonder is Aniccaa a higher law than Karma, and so on and so forth...

Comment: Tibet was invaded 65 years ago, few of us experienced "the context changing". If you'd like to reopen maybe ask a more specific question. You might see also e.g. [Expaining The Holocaust & karma to a non-Buddhist](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/23826/254), e.g. about kamma.

Comment: Another thing I mistrust about this question as-is is that someone is likely to answer it with (not an anti-Chinese but) an anti-Tibetan and anti-Dalai Lama answer, that consists of and includes statements about politics and history. But, the politics and history of Tibet and His Holiness' role in that, are topics which IMO the users of site aren't experts at assessing and putting into context, so may be more on topic on the History.SE or Politics.SE or Skeptics.SE sites -- so instead I'd rather you try to keep the questions more specifically about Buddhism and/or personal practice and so on.

Comment: I am sorry @ChrisW, didn't mean to be passive-aggressive. I did get the answer in the holocaust link. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this question has been asked 2500 years ago. Please see [Mahāparinibbānasutta DN16](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/sujato):

> [I will wipe out these Vajjis, so mighty and powerful! I will destroy them, and lay ruin and devastation upon them!](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/sujato)